# terraform azurerm function app settings host.json documentation missing

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm working with an existing pipeline deploying AzureRM resources with terraform code. One of the current requirements is to set the logging level to Debug on the  "Function app settings" page of a function. Here is where things get fuzzy, as i can't seem to find any examples or documentation. The part I'm trying to set is the **host.json** section.

Here an example of what I'm trying to set is in the code section. image link : https://ibb.co/v3Nxb6d

In the terraform code i have a section for `app_settings` , that works fine. I have looked at the terraform documentation, and googled around, can't find anything about it.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Debug"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So what is the issue you want to know?

Comment: how to add those host.json settings in the terraform code ? the printscreen is from a demo function where it is set-up manually, i need to commit the terraform code to update all functions in all the environments managed by the pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `host.json` file is generated automatically. When function host starts, it reads log level from `host.json` and inject ILogger instance with corresponding filter rules.

Host configurations are not env variables, its settings cannot be overwritten by anything at the ARM level. However there are also various things that you can configure via App Settings. You could refer to this [wiki](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Configuration-Settings).